# Android: build project with different sets of resources

Tags: android, gradle, build

I have got project that have more different sets of resources (images and xml with strings). Every set contains resources with identical names, just images and strings itself are different. Is there some easy way using gradle to build project with one specific set or maybe build more apks with all sets at once?

I haven't used gradle for difficult operation before and I quess it won't be that easy, so I will be happy for every hint, where I could find more information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make Product Flavors for your application.

Look at this tutorial:

https://objectpartners.com/2015/03/31/using-android-product-flavors-to-build-full-and-demo-version-of-the-app/

Cheers.